# MVC 5 C# Web App use forms or windows authentication against AD

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 Application working with forms authentication against AD.  I would like to have the ability to use windows authentication if the user is already signed into AD on their machine and if not go to forms authentication where they can enter their AD credentials.

Is there a relatively straight forward way to handle this without writing a custom membership class?  And if so how?  Any help would be appreciated.  I have seen several posts about not mixing the types of authentication but I don't use any local authentication.  It is all against AD.  Is this still not supported?

Answer (score 1):

It's not technically supported by IIS (if that's what you're using), but you can enable both forms and windows authentication.

In whatever controller you are using in the "loginUrl" of your forms authentication settings (in your Web.config) you can check the headers to determine if the user is logged in, for instance:

Given this setting

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Login">
```

You can do this:

```
public class LoginController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string windowsUserName = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(windowsUserName))
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(^\w+)\\", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            string userName = regex.Replace(windowsUserName, string.Empty);

            // validate the user name against ad here

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);

            this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            // if the user isn't signed in with AD credentials you can send an
            // "unauthorized" http code and the browser (excluding Firefox)
            // will try to send credentials (if available).

            // you will have to manage staying out of a redirect loop
            // many options here: set and check a cookie, session, headers, etc.
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

1. An anonymous (unauthenticated) request hits the LoginController

   - System sends an unauthorized http response
2. An authenticated request hits the LoginController

   - System checks the header and compares the value to AD (example of comparing with AD below)

When I had to do this for a particular app, I also checked the requests host address (to make sure it was on the same domain as the server, otherwise I didn't even bother:

```
IPAddress address = null;

if (IPAddress.TryParse(Request.UserHostAddress, out address))
{
    if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(address))
    {
        address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).FirstOrDefault(ip => !IPAddress.IsLoopback(ip));
        if (address == null)
        return View();
    }

    IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(address);

    bool isPartOfDomain = false;

    foreach (IPAddress hostEntryAddress in entry.AddressList)
    {
        if (String.Equals(address.ToString(), hostEntryAddress.ToString()))
        {
            string domain = "Your Domain Here"; // or get it from your configuration settings / db / etc

            using (PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                string computerName = entry.HostName.Replace("." + domain, string.Empty);

                using (ComputerPrincipal computer = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, computerName))

                 if (computer != null)
                {
                    isPartOfDomain = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I usually check against a Domain [PrincipalContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify the user name.

```
DirectoryEntry entry;
string domain = "Your Domain Here",
       userName = "Some User Name";

        using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            using (UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName))
            {
                if (principal != null && (entry = (DirectoryEntry)principal.GetUnderlyingObject()) != null)
                {
                    string userPrincipalName = principal.UserPrincipalName ?? principal.Name;
                    userPrincipalName = userPrincipalName.Substring(0, (userPrincipalName.Contains("@") ? userPrincipalName.IndexOf("@") : userPrincipalName.IndexOf(" ")));

                    bool isValid = string.Equals(userName, userPrincipalName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If I am following this correctly this doesn't actually authenticate the user with their logged in windows credentials to a domain.  The LOGON_USER value could be a user from any domain/machine.  So for example if the user has the same username on the domain and their personal machine it would be the same.  I am not sure how to force windows ntlm auth in the comment validate username against ad here.  Basically I would like to try windows auth against domain X and if they are not signed into domain X prompt for AD credentials.  I can't figure out the auto check.

Comment: @Xaxum I edited the answer to include checking against a doman...the PrincipalContext also has methods for validating a user's credentials (with a password), instead of just taking what the headers supply (it is also a good idea to make sure that the user's client is running on a machine that has a trust relationship with the domain you are interested in (an example is in my answer)

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding principalcontext the user would need to input their password into the application.  It doesn't use NTLM and pull from windows.  So I would still need to prompt if I want to verify the user for real.  Thanks for the additional detail.  It doesn't look like I can truly verify the user without prompting for their password.  You are correct in that several checks could be put in but IP is difficult.  I may do some research on if there is a way to verify Machine is part of domain.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Xaxum I think you might have misunderstood my code snippets: When the domain Principal is created for the specified domain you are using part of the NTLM suite. You do not need to check the user's password at that moment if you have followed a couple of steps (for which I provided samples). 1st, make sure the user's machine is on the same network as the domain controller and has joined the domain (sample 2); 2nd, retrieve the "LOGON_USER" server variable (if it isn't there send a 401...sample 1). Checking the IP address (and verifying that the machine is part of the domain are all sample 2

Comment: I understand what you are saying by using the 2 checks above.  However, if somebody creates a separate domain with the same domain name and computer name the check would pass even though it was a different domain, with the same name.  I can't verify IP address since some IP space is in the private IP space.  I think you could be reasonably sure with the above checks but there is still an opening.  That is why I was looking for the full NTLM exchange.  I did upvote because this led me down some different paths but I can't use for this reason.